# I have never seen whale “in nature” before

Tags: phrase-requests

I am not a native English speaker, and I imagined this scenario:

I am talking about whales, I only see whales on TV and magazines I have never seen them “face to face”.

I have difficulty expressing this “face to face”. 
Should I say

> I have never seen whales in nature before, only on TV and magazines

Or

> I have never seen whales in real life before, only on TV and magazines.

Or there is more correct phrases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've now put this in the right place and chosen a relevant tag. Please see the [tag info](/tags/phrase-requests/info) for details of how to improve this question: "correctness" for replacement phrases in questions like this is **entirely** subjective.

Comment: *...a real whale...* will do.

Comment: I might say "live" or "in the wild".

Comment: @mahmudkoya Those in the pictures aren't bogus actually.

Comment: "In nature" and "in the wild" are close enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can say that you have never seen them *in person*.

> **in person** *phrase*
>   With the personal presence or action of the individual specified.
>   ‘he had to pick up his welfare cheque in person’
>   ‘A few days later I went in person to report that two parcels had gone missing.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_person)

Comment: It's unclear if OP means they have never seen a whale in nature, or never in person. If you have only ever seen whales in the media and in the zoo then you have seen one in person, but not in nature or in the wild. ;)

Comment: What I mean is that I have seen whales in media before, but I’ve never seen them in a zoo or in sea, i.e. I’ve never seen them in their natural habitat or captured in zoos.

Comment: @Asmaa You can also say "[with my own eyes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see-sth-with-your-own-eyes)". It would be idiomatic in the sense you intend, but you might find some quibble about whether watching it on TV counts as seeing something with your own eyes.